# change the keys in Pair RDD [pyspark]

Tags: pyspark

Can I change the key in a pair RDD?

I have created a normal RDD from a CSV FILE ( NAME , AGE , NATIONALITY) using `sc.textFile` command.

I want to create a pairRDD WITH NATIONALITY AS the key and values of ( name , age) .

```
t1 = rdd.map( lamda x : (X.split(",") [2] , x))
```

But `t1.keys()` doesn't show the keys nor does the `t1.values()`

I am using python  and can u help me to create as in scala we have the option to do the same .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `collect()` along with RDD like, `t1.keys().collect()` to print them. Check the below, and I got it.

```
>>> rdd= sc.parallelize([['Mike',25,'XXX'],['Sam',45,'YYY'],['Jim',26,'ZZZ']])
>>> rdd.collect()
[['Mike', 25, 'XXX'], ['Sam', 45, 'YYY'], ['Jim', 26, 'ZZZ']]
#Making Nationality as Key, and others as values
>>> t1=rdd.map(lambda x:(x[2],(x[0],x[1])))
>>> t1.collect()
[('XXX', ('Mike', 25)), ('YYY', ('Sam', 45)), ('ZZZ', ('Jim', 26))]

>>> t1.keys().collect()
['XXX', 'YYY', 'ZZZ']

>>> t1.values().collect()
[('Mike', 25), ('Sam', 45), ('Jim', 26)]
```

Comment: Hi Jim                                                                                                                    
  The question looks silly                                                                                   
   pair1rdd = fprdd.map(lambda x : (x[2] ,(x[0],x[1]))  and enter command takes  to next line instead of executing the command ..                                                                                   Any help is highly appreciated